# Why is this question still like this?

Tags: discussion

I have no idea whether this is recent or old but why has this question *[What databases and listing sites exist for anime, manga, etc?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/4696/what-databases-and-listing-sites-exist-for-anime-manga-etc?answertab=active#tab-top)* got the following

> We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed.

Could someone explain why? Is the answer not good enough? If not what are some reasons that could be pointed out to improve it?

I couldn't think of any and the answer seems very well researched and written. Might need a few tweaks e.g. such as adding new sites if anyone knows any but other than that I do not believe this notice is necessary.

Also what would be the point in adding another answer? Can we remove the notice/caption for this question.

Comment: maybe to warn new user not to add answer that only contain one link or such?

Comment: @ShinobuOshino I don't think any new user will actually answer this question - I mean it happened once since I can see the deleted answer but other than that, that's about it. We can always protect it but there seems to be no point really. Also there would be no point since if you wanted to add a link, you should really just edit it into the current answer.

Answer (score 2):

We will rarely limit questions to one answer per question, and this post notice serves as a notice to users who want to add answers.

This means that if a user wants to add a new answer, we expect a long and well thought out answer (like the existing one).